# MySQL statement UPDATE IF equal to or greater than else do nothing

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE `equipment` SET `currentHours`= :unitHours, `lastUpdate`= :lastUpdate WHERE `equipType`= :equipType AND `unitNumber`= :unitNumber'); 

    $stmt ->execute(array(':lastUpdate'=> $dateToday, ':unitHours' => $unitHours, ':equipType'=> $equipType, ':unitNumber'=> $unitNumber));
```

I need to only update the `currentHours` if the value is equal to or greater than the value currently stored in that row. Is this possible with a MySQL statement or do I have to do it in PHP? I am new to programming so sorry in advance if this sounds like a simple question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE `equipment` SET `currentHours`= :unitHours, `lastUpdate`= :lastUpdate

 WHERE `equipType`= :equipType AND `unitNumber`= :unitNumber

AND
    currentHours<:unitHours
```

The above updates **only** records with current hours lower than the input, it won't update **all** last update field that matches the rest of the condition.
If u want to update the **field** currenthours **only** when it is lower than the input, but update the lastupdate field regardless, then:

```
UPDATE `equipment` 
SET `currentHours`= IF(currentHours<:unitHours,:unitHours,currentHours), 
`lastUpdate`= :lastUpdate

WHERE `equipType`= :equipType AND `unitNumber`= :unitNumber
```

Comment: he wrote "equal to or greater than the value currently stored" so it will be currentHours<=:unitHours

Comment: @Gustek If they are equal, the Update will not change anything, wiil it?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 (Isn't it the god of death?) it is cutomary to accept the answer if it is the solution.

Comment: I had to wait a couple minutes haha

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka I looked into the god of death comment and it came up as "Yama" is the god of death in Hinduism. "Yamaha" is a Japanese motorcycle manufacturer.

Comment: So..which one do u prefer to be called after ;-) in my language they both r written the same...

Comment: "Yamaha" I think "Yama" would make the girls stay away from me.

Comment: @Gustek: You are right. Yamaha should clarify in which cases he wants the `lastUpdate` column to be updated (a `CASE` may be needed if he wants that column to be updated anyway, regardless of the `currentHours` update or not.)

Comment: @ypercube the query that was posted and accepted as the answer does exactly what I need it to. I only wanted the `currentHours` updated if it was greater than the value already stored, but updating the `lastUpdate` column should be done every time the query is ran which it is doing perfectly.

Comment: Yamaha32088 Read the comments by @Gustek and ypercubem if what they say is correct (as is one way to understand your question) then the solution is completely different.

Comment: @Yamaha No, it isn't (doing perfectly). For the rows that have `currentHours >= :unitHours`, the `lastUpdate` column is **not** updated by this query.

Comment: @ypercube is right, I will update my answer to have both cases

Comment: Your right my testing was wrong I tested it when the values were `=`